# Issue with SBJsonParser

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, nsarray, nsdictionary

my iPhone application is receiving from my web service this json string:

```
{"res":true,"users":[{"id":"79","username":""},{"id":"81","username":""},{"id":"83","username":""},{"id":"80","username":""},{"id":"82","username":""}]}
```

I'm handling it with the following code:

```
SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
NSError *error = nil;

NSDictionary *dictionary = [jsonParser objectWithString:responseString error:&error];
```

where `responseString` is the string received with the JSON.

Now if i check for `[[dictionary valueForKey:@"res"] boolValue]` it is correctly a boolean.
The problem is with `[dictionary objectForKey:@"users"]` I don't understand what kind of object it is.

I try also with this:

```
NSLog(@"Is of type NSString?: %@", ([[dictionary objectForKey:@"users"] isMemberOfClass:[NSString class]])? @"Yes" : @"No");
NSLog(@"Is of type NSArray?: %@", ([[dictionary objectForKey:@"users"] isMemberOfClass:[NSArray class]])? @"Yes" : @"No");
NSLog(@"Is of type NSMutableArray?: %@", ([[dictionary objectForKey:@"users"] isMemberOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]])? @"Yes" : @"No");
NSLog(@"Is of type NSDictionary?: %@", ([[dictionary objectForKey:@"users"] isMemberOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])? @"Yes" : @"No");
NSLog(@"Is of type NSMutableDictionary?: %@", ([[dictionary objectForKey:@"users"] isMemberOfClass:[NSMutableDictionary class]])? @"Yes" : @"No");
```

but it always says `No`.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you tried putting a break point at 'NSDictionary *dictionary = [jsonParser objectWithString:responseString error:&error];' and checking what dictionary points to?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `isKindOfClass:` instead of `isMemberOfClass:` because collections are usually implemented as class clusters in Cocoa.

Also, `NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass([[dictionary objectForKey:@"users"] class]))` is much shorter to write than checking every possible class individually.

Comment: Or you could notice the `[ ]`'s and that tell's you that it's an array.

Comment: Sure, but that's not really the point here. It also depends a lot on the specific implementation of the JSON parser how exactly an array is represented – it could be immutable or mutable, a custom subclass, etc.

Comment: What difference would it make if it was mutable or immutable it would still be represented as an NSArray in Objective-C?